# Displaying the description from Google Calendar on a wordpress site

Tags: css

I'm using a google calendar wordpress plugin on a site. I want to display the [description] as well as the [title]. The default from the plugin is this:

```
<strong>[title]</strong>

[when]
[location]
<div>[description]</div>
[link newwindow="yes"]See more details[/link]
```

This results in the title showing and the other fields showing when you mouse over. But I want the description field to also show automatically along with the title field, which does show. I thought I could change it to this:

```
<strong>[title] [description]</strong>

[when]
[location]
<div>[description]</div>
[link newwindow="yes"]See more details[/link]
```

but the description still does not display. I am fairly new at this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-calendar-events/ this pacakge ??

Comment: yes thats the one.